# How to Refresh image shown in home page by static CMS with same name and location

Tags: image, cms-block, browser

I have a CMS block that shows three images, top.jpg, mid.jpg, and bottom.jpg.

The CMS block contains:

> ..and so forth..

My idea was to keep the same names so someone in charge of the content could  just ftp the files with new content as necessary.. but then I found out about the issue that they are not refreshed by the browsers after the first time they showed the page, because the browsers understand that they already have the files in cache.

What is the best way to manage a need this in Magento?   I am running M2 ver 2.1.    Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!
AC

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the http headers to control the end users and CDN caches. Which usually involves using mod_rewrite headers in apace or such in nginx. Using an HTML meta tag isn't recommended as proxies/CDN won't recognize it.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4480304/158325
- https://belvg.com/blog/cache-control-header.html
- https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html